# z-index not working even with absolute positioning

Tags: css, z-index

I am trying to create a fish and its backfins don't go behind its body even if I use the z-index property properly set. What's wrong with this? I know I can only use z-index with positioned elements. What's the other thing that might influence the properties behavior?

```css
.fish{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.fish-body {
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    left: 23.5%;
    background: black;
    width: 53%;
    height: 45%;
    border-radius: 10% 150% 2% 150%;
    transform: rotate(142deg);

}

.backfin-top{
    position: absolute;
    top: 88%;
    left: 56%;
    background:yellow;
    width: 53%;
    height: 45%;
    transform: rotate(85deg);
    border-radius: 0% 50% 400% 10%;
    z-index:-1;
}

.backfin-bottom{
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    right: -34%;
    background: yellow;
    width: 53%;
    height: 45%;
    border-radius: 10% 400% 10% 50%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="fish">
  <div class="fish-body">
    <div class="backfin-top"></div>
    <div class="backfin-bottom"></div>
  </div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: The actual reason your example isn't working is related to the stacking contexts. You can read more about it here :- https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-z-index

as the answer below has done, simply make your `fish-body` it's own div and not a parent of the two fins

Comment: Interestingly If I delete the transform: rotate(142deg); from the fish-body class the z-index: -1 actually works. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution,

Basically, I had to change your html stucture. Check snippet below

This is required because, first, the

```
 <div class="backfin-top"></div>
 <div class="backfin-bottom"></div>
```

will be drawn on screen, and then the fish body will be drawn

In your case placing the fins inside **fish body div** made `z-index` useless for placing the fins behind the fish.

In the following example `z-index` is not required to place the fins behind.

```css
.fish {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.fish-body {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  left: 23.5%;
  background: black;
  width: 53%;
  height: 45%;
  border-radius: 10% 150% 2% 150%;
  transform: rotate(142deg);
}

.backfin-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 38%;
  left: -4%;
  background: yellow;
  width: 33%;
  height: 25%;
  transform: rotate(217deg);
  border-radius: 0% 50% 400% 10%;
 
}

.backfin-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  right: 70%;
  background: yellow;
  width: 33%;
  height: 25%;
  border-radius: 10% 400% 10% 50%;

  transform: rotate(317deg) scale(-1, -1);
}
```

```html
<div class="fish">
  <div class="backfin-top"></div>
  <div class="backfin-bottom"></div>
  <div class="fish-body">
  </div>
</div>
```

`z-index` on positioned elements and `transform` by itself create new "[stacking contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)" on elements.  Here's what's going on:

Your `.fish-body` element has `transform` set to something other than none, which gives it its own stacking context.

You then add a `fins`, which is a child of `.fish-body`.  This child has `z-index: -1`, setting the stack level of `fins` **within the stacking context of `.fish-body`**  Setting `z-index: -1` on `fins` does not place it behind `.fish-body` because `z-index` only has meaning within a given stacking context.

When you remove `transform` from `.fish-body` it removes its stacking context, causing `.fish-body` and `.fins` to share a stacking context (that of `<html>`) and making `fins` go behind `.fish-body`.

Comment: Thank you! I fiddled with this for a bit and realized that just by deleting the transform property from .fish-body and declaring it in the .fish class it'll work without actually changing the stack order. Do you know why?

Comment: thank you I didn't know transform property was capable of doing such thing:)

Answer (score 0):

index is not working in your case because we cannot overwrite the z-index of parent div. If we want use z-index then all the elements should be a child of same parent and we should use position as well. Please take  a look on following code and output.

```css
    .fish{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
        position: relative;
}
.fish-body {
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    left: 23.5%;
    background: black;
    width: 53%;
    height: 45%;
    border-radius: 10% 150% 2% 150%;
    transform: rotate(142deg);

}
.backfin-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 0;
    background: yellow;
    width: 40%;
    height: 25%;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
    border-radius: 0 50% 400% 10%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.backfin-bottom {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 46px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 40%;
    height: 25%;
    border-radius: 10% 400% 10% 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="fish">

    <div class="fish-body"></div>
            <div class="backfin-top"></div>
            <div class="backfin-bottom"></div>
    

</div>
```

Comment: I get it and I see it's working thank you! Though, I can't quite comprehend why this example at the freecodecamp's website: https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/basic-css/create-a-custom-css-variable/  works fine with the same structure I used to create my fish?